# Shell script to perform telnet session to ser2net

Tags: shell-script, expect, telnet

I have setup a xenserver (free) hosting a VM (Debian 7.5).
On this xenserver I have attached a serial GSM modem.
I have configured xen to run ser2net so I have a serial proxy available.
This works perfectly local and remote (telnet). Now on the Debian VM I am running zenoss and I wish to use the paging functionality. I'm creating a bash script to simulate the telnet session and sending a  message. This script is only working for 50%.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
set number [lindex $argv 0]
set message [lindex $argv 1]
spawn telnet 10.10.0.52 3333
#wait?
sleep 1
send AT+CMGS="$number"\r;
expect ">"
send "$message^Z";
interact
#...
```

Running the script:

```
administrator@debian:/home/zenoss$ ./sms.sh +32486000000 xxen
spawn telnet 10.10.0.52 3333
Trying 10.10.0.52...
Connected to 10.10.0.52.
Escape character is '^]'.
AT+CMGS="+32486000000"
> xxen^Z
```

I'm having problems sending the control character <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to
initiate the send, it hangs. *(note: the ^Z is the real character inserted with vi)* Plus how should I go about multiple recipients? And
how should I exit and disconnect.

EDIT: I tried

> send "$message^Z";

to

> send "$message"^Z;

but got this result:

```
administrator@debian:/home/zenoss$ ./sms.sh +32486000000 xxen
spawn telnet 10.10.0.52 3333
Trying 10.10.0.52...
Connected to 10.10.0.52.
Escape character is '^]'.
AT+CMGS="+32486000000"
> extra characters after close-quote
    while executing
"send "$message"^Z;
interact
#...
"
    (file "./sms.sh" line 10)
```

UPDATE:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
# - VAR
set ctrlz \032
set xt \135
set timeout 15
set host [lindex $argv 0]
set port [lindex $argv 1]
set number [lindex $argv 2]
set message [lindex $argv 3]
# - CONNECT
spawn telnet $host $port
sleep 1
# - SEND
send AT+CMGS="$number"\r;
expect ">"
send "$message$ctrlz";
expect "OK"
# - END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a control character in expect, send an octal character.

```
send $message
send \032
```

or

```
set ctrlZ \032
send "$message$ctrlZ"
```

Ref:

- http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.tcl/sending-the-control-character-in-expect/1847173
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z

Comment: Do you know how I could log all output from within the script?

Comment: You want the `log_file` command

Comment: tried that but I only get log entries when I run the script manually...